# A Question by any other Number

Tags: support

The main page of the site says that there are (currently) 207 Questions. When I hover on the links though, there is a number, which I am guessing is assigned sequentially. Many recent questions are in the 1300 range. One is 872, there is a 211 and a 14. If "question sequence numbers" are over 1300 and yet there are only "207 Questions", did 1100 meet an untimely end?

Comment: For example, on this meta site it says there are 58 Questions, but the number in the link of this very Question is 200. (Qapla'!)

Answer (score 3):

All "posts" are stored in one database table internally; there isn't a separate table for questions and answers.

A "post" [is one of the following](http://data.stackexchange.com/cseducators/query/690914):

- Question
- Answer
- Wiki
- Tag wiki excerpt
- Tag wiki
- Moderator nomination
- Wiki placeholder
- Privilege wiki

There [may be gaps in the numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267921/336144) if the SQL server does something funky, but in theory, if you account for all of the above, the IDs should be sequential.

It also has the interesting side effect of allowing you to link to a question as if it was an answer—`https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/200` does link to this question, but `/a/` is really for answers.

But it would be unlikely that questions alone would have sequential IDs... unless no-one's answering 'em!

Comment: Thank you. It would be interesting to see a schema or diagram of the basic SE database structure.

Comment: @nocomprende The schema is available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/336144), or in the right sidebar [on SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/cseducators/query/new).

Comment: @nocomprende The reverse side effect it true as well. You can link to a tag wiki, answer, or other post with the [https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/314](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/314/104) syntax. That's actually a tag wiki entry. And, in fact, the `/q/` version is used extensively in SE to create links

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver I always feel confused when something specific like a file path syntax is used in an amorphous way. Couldn't they use something else? It would be like having three sets of driving directions that all mysteriously go to the same place. Creepy.

Comment: @nocomprende If you're on Windows, think "shortcut", and if you use *nix, think "link." Either one can create file paths where multiple _roads lead to Rome_. Web sites do that for many reasons; SEO, user convenience, and developer convenience among them.